# mui datatables change "Sorry,no matching records found" message

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I'm using MUIDataTable and every time the data array is empty a message is displayed:
"Sorry,no matching records found" .
I want to custom this message so i could write whatever i want.
i would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to check the documentation first :)
Here is the documentation for it: https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables#localization

```
<MUIDataTable
  options={{
    textLabels: {
      body: {
        noMatch: 'Your custom message here',
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: thanks buddy, I'm new to React so i didn't think of it at first sight